# Django chat working on project_ip:8000 but not on project_ip

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

My django chat is working if I run my project on port xx.xx.xx.xx:8000 but the moment I run
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000`
to map 8000 to 80, to run my project on ip xx.xx.xx.xx the chat doesn't work, why is this happening ?
My project is running on ec2 ubuntu instance

Comment: Do you have port `80` open in the security group attached to the EC2 instance?

Comment: yes, the whole project is working but only the socket thing is not working and Ihave used in memory channel layer in that